# System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile Out of memory exception error

Tags: asp.net, .net, bitmap

I don't have much knowledge in .Net. and I'm facing Out of memory exception whenever I try to run the **System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(imagePath)** command, Could you please assist in this. The image sizes are less than 1MB and they don't seem to be corrupted tome(can open them using any viewer),  Also i am disposing the image afterwards(as i noticed people suggested this in different solutions)

here is the code:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Server.MapPath(urlToProcess)) Then
                    output.Text = output.Text & "if succeed<br>"
                    imagePath = Server.MapPath(urlToProcess)

                    output.Text = output.Text & imagePath & " "

                    bmpImg = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(imagePath)
                    imgFormat = bmpImg.RawFormat
                    itemName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Server.MapPath(urlToProcess))

                    If imgFormat.Equals(Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif) Then
                        gifIMG = True
                        'get gif image
                        bmpImg = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(imagePath)
                        'trim away extension from end
                        trimmedImgName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Server.MapPath(urlToProcess))

                        'Map a new path
                        urlToProcess = currWorkingDir & "/" & trimmedImgName & ".jpg"
                        imagePath = Server.MapPath(urlToProcess)

                        'save to jpeg format
                        bmpImg.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                        itemName = trimmedImgName
                        'Need to write delete function

                    End If
                    bmpImg.Dispose()

                    If Request.QueryString("s_r") = "checked" Then
                        width = Request.QueryString("s_w")
                        height = Request.QueryString("s_h")
                        AR = Request.QueryString("sAR")
                        measureType = Request.QueryString("spxpct")
                        resizeSourceImage(urlToProcess, itemName & "_s.jpg", height, width, AR, measureType)
                        'output.Text = output.Text & urlToProcess & "<br>"
                    End If

                    If Request.QueryString("n_r") = "checked" Then
                        width = Request.QueryString("n_w")
                        height = Request.QueryString("n_h")
                        AR = Request.QueryString("nAR")
                        measureType = Request.QueryString("npxpct")
                        resizeSourceImage(urlToProcess, itemName & "_n.jpg", height, width, AR, measureType)
                        'output.Text = output.Text & "n resize<br>"
                    End If

                    If Request.QueryString("l_r") = "checked" Then
                        width = Request.QueryString("l_w")
                        height = Request.QueryString("l_h")
                        AR = Request.QueryString("lAR")
                        measureType = Request.QueryString("lpxpct")
                        resizeSourceImage(urlToProcess, itemName & "_l.jpg", height, width, AR, measureType)
                        'output.Text = output.Text & "l resize<br>"
                    End If

                    'remove temp jpg file of a gif source
                    If gifIMG Then
                        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Server.MapPath(urlToProcess)) Then
                            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Server.MapPath(urlToProcess))
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    output.Text = output.Text & itemName & " cannot be found.<br>"
                End If
```

Answer (score -1):

System.Drawing.Bitmap implements IDisposable.

Try to put :

```
using bmpImg = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(imagePath)


End Using
```

Comment: I get a compilation error. it seems that "using" in using bmpImg is the one causing it

Comment: if you got option strict on you need to write out the full `using bmpImg As Bitmap = `. Also, to avoid unnecessary casts, I advise you use `new Bitmap(imagePath)` instead of `FromFile(imagePath)`. Internally it does the same, but this one actually returns an object of type `Bitmap` instead of `Image`.

Comment: @Nyerguds actually it is declared earlier as " Dim bmpImg as Bitmap "

Comment: using variables are _never_ declared earlier. They should only exist inside the "using" block.